# Need to predict into the future, past training and test data, for financial time series. Keras/Tensorflow/LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

Calling the necessary libraries

```
import math
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from datetime import datetime
```

Getting the times series data that I need

```
#Interval required 5 minutes
dataset_train = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=x', period='5d', interval='15m')
#Print data
dataset_train'
```

Plotting time series data

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.title('EURUSD History')
plt.plot(dataset_train['Close'])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Prices ($)')
```

setting the training data parameters

```
close_prices = dataset_train['Close']
values = close_prices.values
training_data_len = math.ceil(len(values)* 0.8)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(values.reshape(-1,1))
train_data = scaled_data[0: training_data_len, :]

x_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])
    
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
```

Test data parameters

```
test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len-60: , : ]
x_test = []
y_test = values[training_data_len:]

for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
  x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])

x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
```

The LSTM Model

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(layers.Dense(25))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.summary()
```

Fitting the model

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size= 1, epochs=3)
```

Carrying out the predictions

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(predictions - y_test)**2)
rmse
```

Plotting the model outcomes

```
data = dataset_train.filter(['Close'])
train = data[:training_data_len]
validation = data[training_data_len:]
validation['Predictions'] = predictions
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Model')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Close Price USD ($)')
plt.plot(train)
plt.plot(validation[['Close', 'Predictions']])
plt.legend(['Train', 'Val', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
print(train)
print(validation[['Close', 'Predictions']])
```

That's the code for the model, training, and test data predictions. I just need to know how to make real time predictions into the actual future for 3 15 min bars of data in advance.

Comment: So you want to know, how to do actual inference of real-world data or what is your problem?

Comment: Yes that’s what I need. To predict data beyond the test set, prices that haven’t occurred yet

Comment: What you need is a dataset with time series values and an expected outcome (ground truth) for the NEXT time series (always one displaced, to predict values of the future). You can then train with n-grams of your dataset (n entries of the time series combined as input to predict the desired outcome of the NEXT time step). When you trained your model this way, you can predict the next values in inference mode exactly the same. So your input will be a time series containing n-steps and your output will be the NEXT time step. Recurrent Neural Networks (like LSTMs) are recommended for such tasks.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :) Machine Learning is a mix between experimental maths, luck and magic (my maths professor once said)

Comment: Haha I’ll remember that, it’s definitely ringing true for me